# Как подключать внешние библиотеки к rust?

Tags: библиотеки, rust

Данный код не компилируется, проблема в строчке `extern crate camera_capture;`. Как добавить к rust внешнюю библиотеку? Я скачал репозиторий,но как и где прописать к нему путь?

```
extern crate camera_capture;

fn main() {
    let cam = camera_capture::create(0).unwrap();
    let cam = cam.fps(5.0).unwrap().start().unwrap();
    for _image in cam {
        println!("frame");
    }
    println!("done");
}
```

Прописал в cargo.toml следующий строки, не помогло

```
[lib]
name = "camera_capture"
path = "/home/anton/dev/rust_test_proj/libs/camera_capture"
```

Comment: В издании языка 2018 `extern crate` не нужно. Добавьте `edition = "2018"` в `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 2):

Если библиотека есть в реестре crates.io, ее можно указать по имени и версии, тогда cargo загрузит ее автоматически:

```
[dependencies]
camera_capture = "0.5"
```

Для справки, локальные зависимости в `Cargo.toml` можно описывать так:

```
[dependencies]
camera_capture = { path = "../libs/camera_capture" }
```

Этот способ, впрочем, не годится для кода, которым можно делиться с другими разработчиками. Для этого зависимости можно опубликовать на git-репозитории и использовать его URL в спецификации зависимости:

```
[dependencies]
camera_capture = { git = "https://github.com/foo/bar" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Зависимости с [crates.io](https://crates.io/) в `Cargo.toml` описываются как:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "<version>"
```

, где `foo` — это имя пакета, а `version` — требуемая версия, соответствующая синтаксису описанному в [документации](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html); `cargo` сам скачает и соберёт все зависимости.

Соответственно для `camera_capture` я записал бы это как-то так:

```
[dependencies]
camera_capture = ">=0.5.0"
```

---

Дополнительное чтение: [Букварь](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), [описание директив Сargo.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html)

Comment: Синтаксис неверный, должен быть TOML:

```
camera_capture = "^0.5.0"
```

Comment: @mzabaluev, поправил...